# session timeout due to inactivity

Tags: php

I have created a script `login.php` and there I have created a session variable named `logged_in`

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

I am unable to figure out a way to redirect to redirect to my logout.php after session expires due to inactivity. Also should I put the code that expire this session variable. I have Googled the bug and what it suggest is to tweak `php.ini` file in most of the articles. However I came across an article saying that it is not the best practice.
I found the following code on StackOverflow, yet I have no idea where to put it:-

```
<?php
  if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
     // session timed out
  } else {
     // session ok
  }
?>
```

I would like to know the best way to redirect after session expire and suggestions for where to put the code.
Edit: I forgot to mention that I want to know how to manually set a time for the session to expire.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 14):

If you want to logout the user if they try to load a page when they've been inactive for too long, you should put this code at the top of every php file (before ANY other html tags):

```
if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) { //have we expired?
    //redirect to logout.php
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/logout.php'); //change yoursite.com to the name of you site!!
} else{ //if we haven't expired:
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); //this was the moment of last activity.
}
```

Also, put this code at the top of the page where you land when you've successfully logged in:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; //set you've logged in
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); //your last activity was now, having logged in.
$_SESSION['expire_time'] = 3*60*60; //expire time in seconds: three hours (you must change this)
```

On that page you don't have to include the checking code I gave you first.

By the way, don't forget to add `<?php` tags correctly!

Comment: should session_start be included in all the pages?

Comment: @surfine What do you mean exactly by `session_start`? The code `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`? You should put that on the login landing page. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This works for me, but the page I go to after logging in is my applications home page, and if you wait for the timer/session to expire on a page that isn't the home page, then click a link to the homepage the session continues.  How can I make linking back to the homepage when the session is expired log the user out as well?

Comment: @AlMar89 php is not my specialty, really :P I suggest you open a new question, possibly referencing this answer. Sorry!

Comment: Disregard the above comment.  I figured it out.  All I needed to do was have my login page link to a redirect page that has your second block of code and redirects to the homepage.  Then I just had to implement your first block of code on the homepage as well.
Thanks

Comment: @AlMar89 Great you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Implement this idea:

```
$expire_time = 3*60*60; //expire time
if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$expire_time ) {
    echo 'session expired';
    die();
}
else {
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); // you have to add this line when logged in also;
    echo 'you are uptodate';
}
```